# I can not send a data (String) of an activity to a fragment contained in an activity

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to send the ID of a document that is stored in firebase. All the ID's of the documents are printed in a RecyclerView, when you click on any, this should send the ID in String to the Fragment DatosEntregaActivity so that it can search in a collection of "Delivery" the documents that have as field ID the last ID of the Activity.
I've tried it with Bundle, but when clicking, it does not send or does not receive the data sent.

This is the error that throws me when I click on an element of the RecyclerView

```html
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.asus.loginsmk, PID: 15755
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.BaseBundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.asus.loginsmk.Fragments.DatosEntregaActivity.onCreate(DatosEntregaActivity.java:62)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2331)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1386)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1188)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1071)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:115)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2380)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2215)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:649)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1238)
                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1086)
                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1616)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19937)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1489)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:775)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19937)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19937)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1489)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:775)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19937)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19937)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1489)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:775)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19937)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:729)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19937)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1488)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1747)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6774)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:926)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:735)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:667)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:912)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6595)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

This is the activity that will send the data

```html
public class ServicioActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificacion;
    NotificationManagerCompat nM;
    private static final int notificationID = 100;
    String estado;
    private static final String TAG = "ServicioActivity";

    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    List<IdListaVo> listDatos;
    RecyclerView recycler;
    AdapterDatos mAdapterDatos;
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    Task<QuerySnapshot> docRef;
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    String datoFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_servicio);

        listDatos = new ArrayList<>();
        recycler = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.reclycer_ordenes_servicio);

        insertar_orden_servicio();

        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_lista);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        mAdapterDatos.clear();
                        insertar_orden_servicio();

                    }
                },3000);
            }
        });

        estado = "entregado";
        notificacionOrdenServicio(estado);

    }

    public void notificacionOrdenServicio(String stado)
    {
        if (stado == "entregado")
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DatosActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("mitab2",2);

            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK );
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            notificacion = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CHANNEL_ID");

            notificacion.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_smk_icon_notification);
            notificacion.setContentTitle("SMK");
            notificacion.setContentText("Se ha realizado la entrega de su pedido");
            notificacion.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
            notificacion.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });
            notificacion.setAutoCancel(true);
            notificacion.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            nM = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
            nM.notify(notificationID, notificacion.build());
        }


    }

    public void insertar_orden_servicio()
    {

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        docRef = db.collection("DatosGenerales").get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DocumentSnapshot data: " + "succes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots = task.getResult();
                            int tam_botones = queryDocumentSnapshots.size();

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DocumentSnapshot data: " + tam_botones, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            for (DocumentSnapshot document: task.getResult()) {
                                IdListaVo idListaVo = document.toObject(IdListaVo.class);
                                idListaVo.setOrden_servicio(document.getId());
                                idListaVo.setImagen(R.drawable.baseline_local_shipping_black_18);
                                listDatos.add(idListaVo);
                            }

                            mAdapterDatos = new AdapterDatos(listDatos);
                            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                            recycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                            recycler.setAdapter(mAdapterDatos);
                            setOnItemListener();

                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DocumentSnapshot data: sin for" + contador, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            int cantPS = tam_botones;



                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DocumentSnapshot data: " + "not succes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });


    }

    public void setOnItemListener(){
        if(mAdapterDatos!=null)
        {
            mAdapterDatos.setOnItemClick(new AdapterDatos.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    IdListaVo clickedForm=listDatos.get(position);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(ServicioActivity.this, DatosActivity.class);

                    DatosEntregaActivity datosEntregaActivity = new DatosEntregaActivity();

                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("documento", String.valueOf(clickedForm.getOrden_servicio()));

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(clickedForm.getOrden_servicio()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    datosEntregaActivity.setArguments(bundle);

                    /*intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    //intent.putExtra("documento-OS", listDatos.get(position).getOrden_servicio());*/
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

This is el fragment who will receive the data

```html
public class DatosEntregaActivity extends Fragment {
    View mView;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    List<DatosEntrega> listaEntrega;
    Bundle extras;
    String documento_os;
    String tipo_servicio;
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    DocumentReference docRef;
    DatosEntrega datosEntrega;
    
public DatosEntregaActivity()
    {
    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.datos_entrega_fragment_tab, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)mView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_datos_entrega);
        RecyclerViewAdapter_DatosEntrega recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter_DatosEntrega(getContext(), listaEntrega);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        listaEntrega = new ArrayList<>();

        /*if (getArguments() != null) {
            documento_os = getArguments().getString("documento");
        }*/

        documento_os = getArguments().getString("documento");

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        docRef = db.collection("DatosGenerales").document(documento_os);

        tipo_servicio_entrega();

    }

    /*private void consultarBD() {
        extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        documento_os = extras.getString("documento-OS");
        docRef = db.collection("DatosGenerales").document(documento_os);

    }*/

    private void tipo_servicio_entrega() {

        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<
                    DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document.exists()) {

                        tipo_servicio = document.getString("idtiposervicio");

                        String estado = "entregado";
                        String[] entregado = {"ESTATUS", "ENTREGADO A", "FECHA", "OBSERVACIÓN"};

                        if (tipo_servicio.equalsIgnoreCase("LOCAL") || tipo_servicio.equalsIgnoreCase("nacional")) {
                            String[] locNac = {"ORIGEN", "DESTINO", "SERVICIO", "CANTIDAD", "DESCRPCIÓN", "PESO", "DESTINARIO"};
                            String[] infor = {"ORG", "AAAA", "SERV", "CANT", "DESCRP", "BBB", "CCC"};

                            for (int i = 0; i < locNac.length; i++) {
                                listaEntrega.add(new DatosEntrega(locNac[i], infor[i]));
                            }

                            if (estado.equalsIgnoreCase("entregado")) {

                                for (int i = 0; i < entregado.length; i++) {
                                    listaEntrega.add(new DatosEntrega(entregado[i], infor[i]));
                                }

                            }
                        } else {
                            if (tipo_servicio.equalsIgnoreCase("paquete")) {
                                String[] paquete = {"TIPO DE SERVICIO", "N° DE RECOJOS", "N° DE DISTRIBUCIÓN", "SERVICIO", "ORIGEN", "CANTIDAD/TIPO DE MERCADERÍA", "PESO"
                                        , "MEDIDAS", "HORA PROGRAMADA", "DIRECCIÓN DE RECOJO", "NIVEL DE PISO DE RECOJO", "CONTACTO DE RECOJO", "DESTINO", "DIRECCIÓN DE ENTREGA",
                                        "NIVEL PISO DE ENTREGA", "CONTACTO DE ENTREGA", "HORA DE ENTREGA"};

                                for (int i = 0; i < paquete.length; i++) {
                                    listaEntrega.add(new DatosEntrega(paquete[i], "infoPaq"));
                                }


                            } else {
                                if (tipo_servicio.equalsIgnoreCase("almacen")) {
                                    String[] almacen = {"TIPO DE SERVICIO", "AREA M2", "TIEMPO", "TIPO DE MERCADERÍA", "N° PALETS", "CONDICIONES", "DIRECCIÓN", "FECHA DE INICIO", "FECHA DE CULMINACIÓN"};

                                    for (int i = 0; i < almacen.length; i++) {
                                        listaEntrega.add(new DatosEntrega(almacen[i], "infoAl"));
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a `Bundle` to your new `Activity`, you need to the set the `intent`'s extra, not an `Activity`. In your onClick you have the code for it correctly.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ServicioActivity.this, DatosActivity.class);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("documento", String.valueOf(clickedForm.getOrden_servicio()));

intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

And then within your `Activity`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    documento_os = getIntent().getExtras().getString("documento");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: But my DatosEntregaActivity extends Fragment, not is a activity.

Comment: I'll edit my answer, you should name it `DatoasEntregaFragment` instead.

Comment: Hears! You can solve my problem with an idea of ​​your help: 
documento_os = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("documento");